# Website with SSL not reachable for a few users

Tags: ssl, dns, ssl-certificate

My server is not reachable for some users because some get the error "SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG".

I couldn't figure out why, but recently i figured out it is because some **routers have a firewall** blocking my site.

**How did i found this out?** I asked a user having the issue to connect over the 4G network instead of WiFi and then they could reach the website. Also one user told me he got a message from "Trend Micro Malware scanner" saying malware is found on the website.

But i can't find out why this is, i have checked a lot of malware and SSL checkers for my website. And none show errors or malware, the SSL certificate is also installed fine.

**My setup:**

- 1 VPS Server
- 2 domains
- 2 WildCard SSL certificates

The "malware" website:

- https://havana.wetickets.shop/
- https://wetickets.shop/

The always working website (same website, only different URL):

- https://havana.wetickets.ws/
- https://wetickets.ws/

2 days ago i got a brand new SSL certificate for the **wetickets.shop** domain, but before i got this brand new SSL certificate i had the same issues.

It is very hard to solve, because i am not experiencing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that hard if you use the right tools. Running openssl against both domains shows the non working site doesn't send the full certificate chain. Here are their outputs :

```
$ openssl s_client -connect havana.wetickets.shop:443 -showcerts -servername havana.wetickets.ws
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=**3** C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify return:1
depth=**2** C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=**1** C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
verify return:1
depth=**0** OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL Wildcard, CN = *.wetickets.ws
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 **0** s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard/CN=*.wetickets.ws
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 **1** s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 **2** s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 **3** s:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard/CN=*.wetickets.ws
issuer=/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
---

$ openssl s_client -connect havana.wetickets.shop:443 -showcerts -servername havana.wetickets.shop
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=**2** C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, OU = Root CA, CN = GlobalSign Root CA
verify return:1
depth=**1** C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, CN = AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2
verify return:1
depth=**0** OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = *.wetickets.shop
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 **0** s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.wetickets.shop
   i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 **1** s:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2
   i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.wetickets.shop
issuer=/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2
---
```

As you can see in **numbers** I tried to highlight, the .ws domain announces **and** sends 4 certificates, while the .shop domains announces 3 but only sends 2. You need to check your SSL certificate chain file for this one.

Comment: Thanks for looking in to the problem, but i don't think this is the issue. As explained before, the problem also was with the old SSL certificate. But i have added the extra ROOT certificate.

Was hoping for someone having the same issue with the firewall blocking the .shop domain.

Comment: A blocking firewall would end with a connection reset or timeout (usually). _the SSL certificate is also installed fine_ : no, as I pointed out. And maybe the old certificate was also installed badly. We don't know what are doing the _firewalls_ you're mentioning. Are they replacing the server certificate by their own ? If so, do they need to know all of the signing certificates ?

Comment: If over WIFI you're using a proxy which is doing some kind of deep packet inspection, or replacing the certificates, then it can fall because of SSL traffic which is not exactly what is expected. The second trace showed the server was announcing 3 certificates but sending 2 only. Maybe one reason of this failure ?